# Position Div on top of a completely separate div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I am trying to position a div on top of another div programmatically  (javascript or css). The divs are completely separate meaning they look as follows:

```
<div class="bottom">
   <img src="image"></img>
</div>
<div class="Top">
   <img src="image2"></img>
</div>
```

I am new to javascript, css but mosty of the solutions I find are for separate divs inside a div which allows them to use zIndex. Please let me know if you would like me to provide more information regarding my question. Thank you for you help!!

Comment: When you say "on top" are you referring to them overlapping as opposed to one being above (2d plane) the other? Also, why are you averse to putting these `div`s inside another `div` like the questions you mentioned?

Comment: Hello @leigero I am creating the images separately using a library and it was creating a div outside my div. I ended out tweaking the code to have the divs together. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element positioned absolutely doesn't NEED the `z-index` property but it may help prevent conflicts down the road.

```
<style>
    .stack-wrapper { position: relative; }
    .bottom { position: static; z-index: 1; }
    .top { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 2; }
</style>

<div class="stack-wrapper">
    <div class="bottom">
       <img src="image"></img>
    </div>
    <div class="top">
       <img src="image2"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem. If you run into `z-index` conflicts with absolutely positioned elements down the road, remember the element "lower" in the top will render on top

Comment: Thank you for that note ill keep that in mind for sure!

Comment: Can't edit the comment now but "top will render" should read "DOM will render"

Answer (score 2):

You can set these with absolute positioning and change the `z-index` to pick what `div` you want on top. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/27/

```
.top{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;}
.bottom{position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: -1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the wrapper div as position:relative; then the inner div will be position in the top if you use position:absolute; and top:0;  :)